# MongoDB: Project embedded fields in an object with dynamic key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

As part of an aggregation that I am doing, I am ending up with a structure of data in the following format -

```
{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "data": {
    "id1": {"data1": 123, "data2": 234, "data3": 345, "data4": 456},
    "id2": {"data1": 321, "data2": 432, "data3": 543, "data4": 654},
    "id3": {"data1": 111, "data2": 222, "data3": 333, "data4": 444},
    "id4": {"data1": 555, "data2": 666, "data3": 777, "data4": 888},
  }
}
```

The exact same data fields (data1, data2....) will be present in all the id fields (id1, id2...)

In my last step of aggregation - I would like to project only a few fields inside data like **data2** and **data3** like the following -

```
{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "data": {
    "id1": {"data2": 234, "data3": 345},
    "id2": {"data2": 432, "data3": 543},
    "id3": {"data2": 222, "data3": 333},
    "id4": {"data2": 666, "data3": 777},
  }
}
```

What could be my projection step for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below stage :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { /** Re-create 'data' field */
      "data": {
        $arrayToObject: { /** Convert new 'data' array to object */
          $map: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$data" /** Convert 'data' object to array for iteration */
            },
            in: {
              k: "$$this.k",
              v: {
                data2: "$$this.v.data2",
                data3: "$$this.v.data3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OmDFGce7YLE)

**Ref :** [aggregation-operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: Thanks @whoami. But isn't there a simpler **project** step for doing this?

Comment: @VinayNikhil : If you've dynamic keys inside of `data` object -> I guess NO, but if you're sure with having keys `id1`, `id2`, `id3` & `id4` then you can try :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/IrPqCvBhp_Q) (`{
    $project: {
      "data.id1": {
        data2: "$data.id1.data2",
        data3: "$data.id1.data3"
      }}}.......`) or (`{
    $project: {
      "data.id1.data2": 1,
      "data.id1.data3": 1
    }
  }......`)

Comment: The keys inside `data` object are dynamic. Hence the question

Comment: @VinayNikhil : Yes that's why we need to do additional steps or else usually we don't have to..